# Discord: How would you catch a err?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to catch errors from commands and have them logged to the console but it keeps returning with:

```
Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined
```

I have tried to use:

```
.catch(console.error);
```

but this did not return any luck.

My current code:

```
  let guildnamehere = client.channels.get("557505411381461025")
  .catch(console.error);
```

I expected this to log any errors to the console.

Comment: What is a `client.channels.get` ?

Comment: That's a synchronous function (it's `Map.prototype.get`), no promise gets returned from `get` you can just `try` and `catch` it. Also, `get` doesn't throw an error if it doesn't find the property on the Map.

Answer (score 0):

`client.channels.get()` is returning `undefined` and `undefined` does not have a `catch` method,

you can put your code in a `try/catch` block :

```js
let guildnamehere;

try {
  guildnamehere = client.channels.get("557505411381461025")
} catch (e) {
  guildnamehere = "fallback value";
  console.error(e);
}

console.log(guildnamehere);
```